# How to avoid hyper link detect on safari?

Tags: html, safari, mobile-safari

I write a sample web page, which contain a phone number, and fax number, when I run it on safari mobile, it automatically make it become a hyper link, how can I avoid the fax number hyperlinked by the Mobile safari ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `head` element...

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Comment: but I only need one number to be detect , instead of the whole page.

Comment: @user448236 Then you are out of luck, without hacks.

Comment: Safari cannot tell fax numbers from other phone numbers.

Comment: @BoltClock It should be dialing each one it parses and listening for the *ker blonk pling bing* :P